# C How do i specify a POSIX regex that begins in a blank line and ends in a blank line?

Tags: c, regex, pattern-matching, posix

I am trying to write code to scan a file and produce a "match!" message when the tool reads a certain line of code preceded and followed by blank lines. The line I am interested in matching is:

```
Appliance Version 3.1.2
```

Using regex.h, I have a simple tool that compiles my regex pattern then executes it against every line in the file to search for a match. The basic functionality of the tool is fine: I am able to get it to successfully search for various regex matches. Trouble arises when I try to match a regex containing a blank line before and after the above line of text. Here is my precompiled regex:

```
[[:space:]]+\n^Appliance Version [[:alnum:]]$\n
```

I have tried a series of different combinations similar to this, and nothing seems to work. I think it might have to do with \n in which case I would need to figure out a new way to specify the two blank lines. Any insight of POSIX regex would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your regex, it looks like it is trying to match

```
Appliance Version [[:alnum:]]
```

at the end of a line (`$`). That would be matched by

```
Appliance Version 3
```

(`3` is an instance of `[:alnum:]`), but not by

```
Appliance version 33
```

(`[[:alnum:]]` only matches one character), and much less by

```
Appliance version 3.1.2
```

(the above problem, and also `.` is not an instance of `[:alnum:]`)

So at a minimum you need to change `[[:alnum:]]` to `[.[:alnum:]]*` (or some such).

In addition, your use of `^` and `$` is redundant with the explicit `\n`, but nothing in the regex requires the match to be preceded or followed by a blank line. For example, `[[:space:]]\n` would happily be matched with the line:

Not a blank line, but with a blank at the end: \n

(where I've written the `\n` explicitly to show the blank character at the end of the line.)

**Matching blank lines**

A single blank line is matched with `^[[:space:]]*$`. That does not match the newlines at either end. If you want to match a blank line *before* something, use: `^[[:space:]]*\nSOMETHING`. To match a blank line *after* something: `SOMETHING\n[[:space:]]*$`. Or, if you really want a blank line before and after: `^[[:space:]]*\nSOMETHING\n[[:space:]]*$`. (But that won't match if SOMETHING happens to be the first line of the input, for example. Or the last line.)

Comment: ".. or some such": `[[:alnum:]]*` (I think `\w*` should also work).

Comment: @Jongware: 3.1.2 won't match either of your suggestions. `.` is not a word character, no matter how you look at it.

Comment: ah right. I think I mis-interpreted the square brackets for round ones, as in a repeat-group. :(

Comment: thank you for the help with the [.[:alnum:]] @rici I still can't seem to figure out the blank line issue. I tried ^[:space:].$ and the program still does not recognize blank lines.

Comment: @Umphishrey'sMcGee: Edited answer with patterns for blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

As @rici notes, you cannot combine `\n^` to match two blank lines -- the markers `^` and `$` match a *position*, not a literal `\n` character.

To match a blank line, use `\n\n`, or -- better because you probably don't want to *do* anything with the hard return that ends the line above, `(?<=\n)\n` at the start. You can leave the `\n\n` at the end, though.

Comment: when trying (?<=\n)\nAppliance I receive a seg fault. I also tried ^[:space:]*$ to just search for all blank lines in my text file, and it found none of them

Comment: If that's literally what you tried, then it didn't work because it's Bad Syntax. Try `^[[:space:]]*`$` instead.

Comment: @Jongware: It's syntactically correct; just not what he means. It means any number of characters from the set: `:,a,c,e,p,s` :)

Comment: @rici: *very* good! Should I change it to "Good Syntax But Probably Not What You Meant"?